# Printing a double to std::cout results in Segmentation fault (C++)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, mingw

I am new to C++ and want to print out a double value. It is not that I actually need to print that value, I just want to know what is going wrong here.

This is my code (`HelloWorld.cpp`):

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    double i = 5.5;
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Executing this with the debugger attached results in the following error:

```
Thread 1 hit Breakpoint 1, main () at src/HelloWorld.cpp:4
4       double i = 5.5;
Thread 1 received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00000000929ba260 in ?? ()
```

When I put a breakpoint in there, creating and assigning the variable is no problem. The error only occurs once the program is supposed to print that value. Executing the exe without the debugger results in no output at all. The same happens when I replace the `double` with a `long double` or `float`. Printing anything else works fine (Strings, `char`, `int`, `short`, etc.).

I am using Visual Studio Code and MinGW (`x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0`). VS Code is using following files for compilation / debugging:

- [c_cpp_properties.json](https://pastebin.com/hjFvJzHL)
- [launch.json](https://pastebin.com/aL318MyC)
- [tasks.json](https://pastebin.com/gParZB93)

And [here](https://pastebin.com/xJGmJHet) you can see the complete output, in case that helps.

Any Idea what I am doing wrong here? Thank you.

**EDIT:**

When compiling manually using `g++ -g .\src\HelloWorld.cpp -std=c++11 -o HelloWorld.exe` (or just `g++ .\src\HelloWorld.cpp -o HelloWorld.exe`) and running that from the console, the same happens (no output).

I installed MinGW from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/) using the following settings:

- Version: `8.1.0`
- Architecture: `x86_64`
- Threads: `posix`
- Exception: `seh`
- Build revision: `0`

**EDIT 2:**

Found the problem. There was an old version of gcc lurking in my PATH (maybe from Visual Studio or MSSQL Server?). I just move the current gcc to the top of PATH and now it's working fine. Thank you all for your help!

Comment: Sounds like you have your toolchain set up incorrectly.

Comment: That is very perplexing. The code certainly isn't at fault, and that you can print other kinds of data is puzzling. I second @PasserBy with "something about your environment is not sane" (MinGW would be my guess) but this is hard to debug from the information here.

Comment: When I compile manually using `g++ -g .\src\HelloWorld.cpp -std=c++11 -o HelloWorld.exe`, the program does not output anything as well. So something is wrong with minGW?

Comment: With correctly installed environment and toolchain it should work. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b778035a34351c18 So we can't know what is wrong with yours.

Comment: Yep, it works with the right compiler: https://segfault.stensal.com/a/6lHycz1xUH6kaDHV

Answer (score 0):

As many pointed out, this should usually work. The problem was with my setup: I had an old version of gcc somewhere in my PATH variable (version 4.1). Moving the path of the newer version to the beginning of PATH resolves the issue. Thank you all for helping.

To check weather the same happens to you you can do the following: execute `g++ --version` in your project directory. Compare this with the output of `g++.exe --version` when you are in the directory where gcc is installed (for me, this was `C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\mingw64\bin`).